# Application slowness issue in Chrome

Tags: performance, google-chrome, httprequest, cache-control, timing

When too many users are accessing the same records, some of the **requests are being stalled** for more than **3 minutes**.

But the requests are working fine when we directly use the ip of the server instead of using domain.

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

[image]